# For what is the function-like macro Yield() in winbase.h (line 97)?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, macros, header

There is a weird function-like macro in the header file `winbase.h` at line 97 as follows:

```
#define Yield()
```

For what is it?

Comment: You can open those header files and see why DBG is undefined. Probably it's wrapped around another define which evaluates to false.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 3.x used cooperative multitasking model. All apps (also called "tasks") used to run in the same memory space on single thread. Usually, switching between tasks was performed by `GetMessage` API in the app's main message loop. `Yield()` used to be the way to voluntarily switch to another app (e.g., if doing a lengthy CPU-bound processing). Here's a [related MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117567) which has still survived.

Of course, `Yield()` API like that doesn't make sense with the modern multi-threaded, multi-process OS architecture. **So, Microsoft replaced it with an empty macro in attempt to achieve compile-level code compatibility**.

Interestingly enough, in some form `Yield()` has been [reincarnated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield.aspx) in .NET 4.5. Its purpose is to defer the continuation of an asynchronous method on the current  [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) (or on a pool thread, if there is no synchronization context). The interesting part of that is, using `Task.Yield()` within the main UI thread of a .NET app actually allows to organize a similar level of cooperative multitasking Windows 3.x had to offer.

Comment: The real issue is: I have a member function named Yield, now I can't use this name because it has be defined as an evil macro. I like the name very much for its exact meaning in my class. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Simply do `#undef Yield` in your `stdafx.h`, after `windows.h` but before any of your own include files.

Comment: Is there a way to undefine a macro through the compiler's option? For example, -DName=1 can define a macro; Is there a way to undefine?

Comment: In other words, is there a way to undefine a specified macro through the compiler's option?

Comment: `-Umacroname` allows to undefine a predefined macro, but that would not help you, because `Yield` will get defined again - by `winbase.h`. If you don't want to use `#undef Yield` in your own code (after including `windows.h`), try the other way round: define it in the compiler's option: `-DYield=Yield`. See if that takes precedence.

Comment: If you see that error, then your best bet would be to use `#undef`. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585701/handling-macro-redefinition-without-modifying-h-files-c-c-language).